# Setup unique user before tasks run?

Tags: python, locust

How does one setup a user before any "tasks" are run? I would like to populate a bunch on self.my_value variables which are to be used in the tasks. I tried doing it in the on_start function but it runs in parallel with the tasks.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi! on_start is not supposed to run in parallel with the tasks (but it will not block other users from running tasks). If you can reliably reproduce it not working like that then perhaps you can file an issue on github? (include your test plan)

Comment: @Cyberwiz Ah. so on_start *is* supposed to run and finish before any tasks?

Comment: It is supposed to run and finish before *that User’s* tasks

Comment: @Cyberwiz Ok thanks, I will have another look to see if it is something I did wrong.